# Django __str__ function on many to one field is not returning the correct output

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm trying to define `__str__` function for models A and D for the purpose having human readable text in the admin site.  The problem is in model D's `__str__` function where `__str__` will return a many_to_one related field, it does not return the format as intended instead it just showa the default 'D object'.

```
class A(models.Model):
    b = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    c = models.CharField(max_length = 32)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.b, self.c)

class D(models.Model):
    e = models.ForeignKey(A)

    def __str_(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.e.b, self.e.c)
```

Comment: So what *does* it return?

Comment: shows 'D object' in  admin site

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? Check that the indentation in your actual code is correct.

Comment: You're missing an underscore from your `__str_` method

Comment: You've got a typo, `__str_()` instead of `__str__()`.

Comment: I'm using Python 2

Comment: Sorry guys, long day at work, Soviut is correct, is just a typo, it's working now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Iain is also correct.

Comment: Glad you fixed the problem. For any other users reading this in future: if you are using Python 2, you need to use the `python_2_unicode_compatible` decorator or define `__unicode__` instead of `__str__`. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/python3/#str-and-unicode-methods) for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a typo in your method name. You wrote `__str_()` when it should be `__str__()`. So when you're calling `str()` on your model, it's calling the inherited `__str__()` method from the parent class.

Comment: I thought Python will give me an error with that typo. I tried _____________str_____ and it still was valid syntax. Why and how is Python doing that?

Comment: Python won't give an error because those are all valid method names. However, if you want to override a method it must be named the same as the method in the parent class.